# .htaccess hide file- url bar

Tags: linux, .htaccess

How can I hide the name of a file in the url bar?

something like:

```
www.test.com/something/
```

and not

```
www.test.com/something/index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use rewrite rules. If you use Apache web server than mod_rewrite is a good choice.
This manual should walk you thought the process of creating successfull rewrite rules : http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite